# Dynamic way of finding special characters and null values of all columns

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with 128 columns. I want to see for each column how many null values and special characters are present. I know for a single column the SQL syntax is quite straight forward:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE col like '#$%' <--for special character
SELECT count(*) - count(col) from table <-- for NULL values count
```

In fact more elegant way to see the special character is

```
SELECT (len([col_name])- len(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
  REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE([col_name],
    '!',''),'@',''),'#',''),'$',''),'%',''),
    '^',''),'&',''),'*',''),' ','')) ) AS Char_Count
    from table
```

My question is:

How to create a dynamic SQL so that it will check all columns and give a result in tabular form?

I tried the following but didn't work. This is for special characters.

```
Declare @sql varchar(max) = ''
declare @tablename as varchar(255) = 'table'

select @sql = @sql + 'select len([' + c.name + '] - len(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE([' +c.name+'],
    '!',''),'@',''),'#',''),'$',''),'%',''),
    '^',''),'&',''),'*',''),' ','')) ); ' 
from sys.columns c
inner join sys.tables t on c.object_id = t.object_id
where t.name = @tablename
EXEC (@sql)
```

Similarly for NA values.

Request any one to provide any hints.

Comment: What is your SQL Server version?

Comment: SQL Server 2016

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible approach to generate a dynamic statement is the following statement using `VALUES` table value construct and the information from system catalog views. Please, consider that:

- I simplified the statement and `NULL` and `?` are the only special cases, so you need to use nested `REPLACE`s.
- I assume, that all the columns in the table are `varchar` columns. If not, you need an additional `CONVERT()`
- `LEN` function returns the number of characters, excluding trailing spaces, so these spaces are excluded from the calculation.

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE Data (
   Column1 varchar(50),
   Column2 varchar(50),
   Column3 varchar(50),
   Column4 varchar(50),
   Column5 varchar(50)
)
INSERT INTO Data
   (Column1, Column2, Column3, Column4, Column5)
VALUES 
   (NULL, NULL, 'abc', 'abc ', 'abc ?_#'),
   ('xyz', NULL, 'abc', 'abc ', 'abc ?_#')
```

Statement:

```
DECLARE @stm nvarchar(max)
SET @stm = N'' 

SELECT @stm = @stm +
     CASE WHEN @stm = N'' THEN N'' ELSE N',' END +
     '('+
     '''' + c.name + ''', '+
     'CASE '+
        'WHEN ' + QUOTENAME(c.name) + ' IS NULL THEN 1 ' +
        'ELSE 0 ' +
     'END, ' +
     'CASE '+
        'WHEN ' + QUOTENAME(c.name) + ' IS NOT NULL THEN LEN(' + QUOTENAME(c.name) + ') - LEN(REPLACE(' + QUOTENAME(c.name) + ', ''?'', '''')) ' +
        'ELSE 0 ' +
     'END) '
FROM sys.columns c
JOIN sys.tables t ON c.object_id = t.object_id
WHERE t.name = 'Data'

SET @stm = 
  'SELECT v.ColName, SUM(v.ColNullCount) AS ColNullCount, SUM(v.ColCharCount) AS ColCharCount ' +
  'FROM Data d ' +
  'CROSS APPLY (VALUES ' +
  @stm +
  ') v (ColName, ColNullCount, ColCharCount) ' +
  'GROUP BY v.ColName ' +
  'ORDER BY v.ColName'

SELECT @stm
EXEC sp_executesql @stm
```

Result:

```
ColName ColNullCount ColCharCount
Column1 1            0
Column2 2            0
Column3 0            0
Column4 0            0
Column5 0            2
```

Comment: @Zhirov: You have actually made NULL and special character together i.e. in single column.What I want is two different columns, one for NULL count and another for Special Characters. So in result I want three columns viz `ColName`, `colCount_NA` and `colCount_SplChr`

Comment: @pythondumb Change the dynamic statement and add one additional column, see the updated answer.